# How to catch an exception that is being thrown by a method java class

Tags: java, exception

I have written a Java class which throws an exception if supplied with wrong input.

I have written a main program wherein I want if my class called throws an exception then my main class should not display the error message thrown but instead it should display an "Error occurred" string.

My Main program:

```
public class TestAbstractFunction {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AbstractFunction l = new LogFunction();
    System.out.print(l+" = ");
    System.out.println(l.eval(2));

    AbstractFunction si = new SineFunction();
    System.out.print(si+" = ");
    System.out.println(si.eval(60));

    AbstractFunction c1 = null;
    for(double i=-10;i<=10;){
        try{
            c1 = new CompositeFunction(si,l);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Err");
        }
        System.out.print(c1+" = ");
        double value = c1.eval(i);
        value = value + s.eval(i);
        System.out.println("f(x) = "+value);
        i = i+0.5;
    }
 }
```

Method in LogFunction Java class which is throwing illegal argument exception:

```
   // concrete implementation of eval for computing square root
        @Override public double eval(double x) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (x < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Log of negative number is     undefined.");
    return Math.log10(x);
}
```

Now am trying to catch this exception in my main method. I have used try catch to do this but compiler just displays illegal argument exception instead of my catch string.

Appreciate your valuable inputs on what I may be doing wrong.

Thanks!!

Comment: Looks like you need the try-catch block to go around your eval method as well. Right now it only encompasses new CompositeFunction().

Comment: the eval method rightly throws an exception and it is expected behaviour now I would like to catch this thrown exception in my main class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can put your code like this

```
for(double i=-10;i<=10;){
        try{
            c1 = new CompositeFunction(si,l);
            System.out.print(c1+" = ");
            double value = c1.eval(i);
            value = value + s.eval(i);
            System.out.println("f(x) = "+value);
            i = i+0.5;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: updating with this code on execution causes an infinite loop

Comment: gotcha! the increment should be done outside try catch...my bad:)

Comment: oops I got it, eval was throwing the exception and I wrongly surrounded my try catch block :(